# Creating a relationship between one field in a table with two fields in another

Tags: ms-access

Is the picture below the only way to create the relationship described in the title with referential integrity? Why does Access not allow me to do this without the "duplicate" table? Thanks!

[image: Picture]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem this workaround is solving. Could you please clarify which columns of which tables you are trying to link and which is the *"duplicate" table*?

Comment: Also *how* you were trying to link the columns (i.e. show your attempted foreign key definitions).

Comment: I wonder if this SO question is related to your problem: [VB.Net & Access - Set two foreign keys, that refer to the same table/field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081055/vb-net-access-set-two-foreign-keys-that-refer-to-the-same-table-field)

Comment: Oh uhh so apparently I was doing everything completely wrong. My goal was to have the CustomerStateID and JobStateID fields have referential integrity with the State table. But I cannot connect both fields with one table. To solve the problem, what I'm supposed to do is have two State tables (one of them a duplicate) so Access knows that CustomerStateID is linked to tblState and JobSiteStateID is linked to tblState_1 instead of being confused about whether the customer or job site is linked to the one state table.

Comment: @Mike I think you got it wrong. You can have 2 relationships from the same table to another. Your diagram shows exactly that.

Comment: To my understanding, the picture does not do what I intended it to do. What I actually should have done was have two tblStates instead of two tblEstimates. Because I am trying to get the StateAbbreviated property from two different state fields in tblEstimates

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see this occurring is if you wrote a query that INNER JOINs twice

EXAMPLE

```
SELECT tblState.*,tbl_Estimate.JobSiteCity,tbl_Estimate1.JobSiteZip
FROM tblState
INNER JOIN tbl_Estimate
ON tblState.ID = tbl_Estimate.JobSiteStateID
INNER JOIN tbl_Estimate AS tbl_Estimate1
ON tblState.ID = tbl_Estimate1.JobSiteStateID;
```

Because you are running `INNER JOIN` twice, ***the graphical representation has to match***. This would indicate the possibility of checking different columns with each `INNER JOIN`

Let's say you are checking for Jersey City but didn't specify the state.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblState.*,tbl_Estimate.JobSiteCity,tbl_Estimate1.JobSiteZip
FROM tblState
INNER JOIN tbl_Estimate
ON tblState.ID = tbl_Estimate.JobSiteStateID
AND tbl_Estimate.JobSiteCity = "Jersey City"
INNER JOIN tbl_Estimate AS tbl_Estimate1
ON tblState.ID = tbl_Estimate1.JobSiteStateID;
```

This should return JobSites in all ZipCodes from Jersey City, NJ and Jersey City, WI

If you collapse the query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblState.*,tbl_Estimate.JobSiteCity,tbl_Estimate.JobSiteZip
FROM tblState
INNER JOIN tbl_Estimate
ON tblState.ID = tbl_Estimate.JobSiteStateID
AND tbl_Estimate.JobSiteCity = "Jersey City"
```

you should get the same result, but the picture should only have `tbl_Estimate` once